# Can MEF Export/Import static classes?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mef

Is it possible to do something like:

```
[Export(typeof(Settings)]
public static class Settings
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Color {get;set;}
}

[Import(typeof(Settings)]
Settings s;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't export a static class, as there is no instance to wire up.  The second line:

```
Settings s;
```

Would be a compiler error, as you can't instantiate a static class.

That being said, this is really not normally necessary.  MEF will automatically create a single instance (by default) of your `Settings` class  (provided it's not static), and set that same instance to any `Import` specified.  This effectively gives you a "singleton-like" class, without any of the downsides of using a static class or a singleton.